# Find and install Mint's default packages into new Ubuntu install

Tags: package-management, nautilus, synaptic

So I use Mint a lot, but wish to switch to Ubuntu due to trivial updating Ubuntu offers.

Problem with Ubuntu is that a lot of neat packages (Such as right click commands for open in terminal etc) don't come pre-installed.

I wish to get a list of packages to install on Ubuntu that are pre-installed on Mint, even just the GUI based ones would be great!

Note: I am **not** trying to get Ubuntu looking like mint, just the GUI packages that make life easy. I am also **not** asking opinions on what are the best GUI packages out there, just what Mint has Ubuntu doesn't.

Comment: This is question you should ask the Mint folk, not at AskUbuntu.

Comment: This is not about Ubuntu. Questions about other Linux distributions can be asked on Unix & Linux,

Comment: I believe this question should be about both Ubuntu and Mint

Answer (score 1):

If you are not able to find that at the [Mint Forum](http://forums.linuxmint.com/) then I would suggest going into [Synaptic Package Manager](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/synaptic-package-manager-beginners-guide-for-ubuntu-users.html), click on the Status button at lower left then click on Installed at upper left to see

[image: a list of installed packages].

Voila! There's your list.

I looked for a way to output a list automatically with apt, but [apparently there isn't](https://askubuntu.com/questions/378650/write-list-of-packages-installed-via-manual-invocation-of-apt-get-to-file). However, you can output a list from Synaptic with `File | Save Markings As` and save the file where you can work with it. Then, install Ubuntu, repeat generating a list of installed packages with Synaptic and saving it, then compare the list with [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/) or your preferred method.

Comment: Please do not answer questions that are about Mint.

Comment: Why not again? Did I ask in the wrong section?

Comment: This question was moved to unix.stackexchange.com by the moderators so you did not have to repost it there.